nvme discover Failed. Failed fo write to /dev/nvme-fabrics: Connection reset by peer
I'm using the tutorial from this NVIDIA link(https://enterprise-support.nvidia.com/s/article/howto-configure-nvme-over-fabrics) to configure NVMe-oF. Initially, everything worked fine, but when I ran nvme discover, I encountered an error as mentioned in the title.
dmesg:
[ 5013.723032] nvme nvme2: rdma connection establishment failed (-104)
Network card: Mellanox CX-6
CPU: FT-5000c
kernel: 5.10.0-60.18.0.50.oe2203.aarch64
MLNX_OFED: 24.07-0.6.1.0
When using nvme discover on the client, there are no error messages in the target's dmesg.
The post here(https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/nvmet-hw-offload-issue/252438) suggests setting nvme num_p2p_queues greater than 0, but the issue persists.
Does anyone know how I can resolve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

To the post:
the post is only about target offload, which is bypassing the kernel stack at the target side. Not relevant to your issue I think

Everyone, the problem is fixed, and when I take the server's Ethernet card down, the problem is fixed. The possible cause is that the ip addresses of my rdma network card and Ethernet network card are set to the same network segment.
